# Check if collection of words (pyenchant)

Tags: python, cpu-word, pyenchant

I want to check if a string in Python is a collection of words using PyEnchant.
For example, I want to somehow check a concatenated string is a word or not:

```
eng = enchant.Dict("en_US")
eng.check("Applebanana")
```

I know this will return false, but I want it to return true, since Apple + banana are legit words by PyEnchant.

Comment: There are endless combinations of legitimate words that are legal words when combined too. Countless others will look like subtle spelling mistakes. Then there are the combinations that when split *differently* become different words. Ever heard of `expertsexchange.com`? And how many words combined are we talking about here? You'll probably have to try out different splits manually and test those words against pyenchant.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I thought the pyenchant library has some function that checks... crap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you limit yourself to words combined from two other words, you can check the combinations yourself:

```
>>> s = "applebanana"
>>> splits = [(s[:i], s[i:]) for i in range(1,len(s))]
>>> splits
[('a', 'pplebanana'), ('ap', 'plebanana'), ('app', 'lebanana'), 
 ('appl', 'ebanana'), ('apple', 'banana'), ('appleb', 'anana'), 
 ('appleba', 'nana'), ('appleban', 'ana'), ('applebana', 'na'), 
('applebanan', 'a')]
>>> any((eng.check(item[0]) and eng.check(item[1])) for item in splits)
True
```

Of course you can expand that to more than two, but this should give you a general idea of where you're headed.

Comment: Thank you.
A lot of complicated then I thought it would be.